# Equivalent of MySQL's  SOURCE command to load a script for TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, osql

In MySQL, you can issue commands like this:

```
drop database foo;
create database foo;
use foo;
source c:\src\bar.sql
```

The `source` statement loads a external script and runs it.

What's the equivalent in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly something like:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -S . -E -d "database name" -i "c:\src\bar.sql"';
```

If you want a specific SQL auth account instead, you can say:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -S . -U user -P pass -d db -i "c:\src\bar.sql"';
```

If you want this to be portable and not hard-code the instance name (the above assumes a default instance) then:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'sqlcmd -S "' + @@SERVERNAME + '" -E'
    + ' -d db -i "c:\src\bar.sql"';

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks. The -d "db_name" is like  USE db_name .